# How can i get multi touch working in Unity on Ubuntu 19.04 on my Acer Aspire A315-51-3879?

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, acer, 19.04

I recently installed Unity on my fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.04 and it works fine except for the touchpad. The multi touch does not work at except for scrolling with two fingers. I have tried going into the settings -> Mouse and Touchpad but that has no options for multi touch. I have also tried using the terminal using `xinput set-prop` to no avail. I'm new to ubuntu so I'm completely lost now. Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be libinput support for unity in 19.10+ there is none now. 
So install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package and reboot. Then ck. System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad

(- Do not be tempted to remove any libinput packages, needed for greeter..